# Are local variables rvalues in C++?

Tags: c++, rvalue

I am reading a textbook from Stroustrup to understand the concept of rvalue and move constructors:

> an rvalue is – to a ﬁrst approximation – a value that you can’t assign
>   to, such as an integer returned by a function call, and an rvalue
>   reference is a reference to something that nobody else can assign to.
>   The res local variable in operator+() for Vectors is an example.

The code referred to in the quote above is listed below.

Question: the local variable `res` can legally appear on the left hand side of an assignment, such as in`res=nullptr`. Why is it seen as an rvalue instead?

```
Vector operator+(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) {

  if (a.size()!=b.size()) throw Vector_size_mismatch{};

  Vector res(a.size()); 

  for (int i=0; i!=a.size(); ++i) res[i]=a[i]+b[i]; 

  return res;

}
```

Comment: Notice the temporary variable that is the result of `a[i]+b[i]`?  That's an rvalue.  It doesn't have a name.  It can be moved from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, local variables are not rvalues. In your example the rvalue is the temporary object that is a copy of res (though a call of the copy constructor or move constructor can be elided) returned by the function.

`res` itself is an lvalue within the function.

Answer (score 2):

> The res local variable in operator+() for Vectors is an example.

This is wrong. `res` is rather a prime example of an lvalue. I’m a bit concerned about your textbook. We don’t have a lot of context, so this could just be an instance of a typo or misleading phrasing. However, if it is a genuine mistake it shows the author’s major lack of knowledge about the fundamentals of the language.

The usual rule of thumb is: “If it has name it cannot be an rvalue. If it doesn’t have a name it is likely to be an rvalue.” This works well, even in cases that might seem confusing at first. For example:

```
// A temporary has no name.
// Therefore: Can call foo() with it.
foo(Object());

void foo(Object&& o)
{
    // o has a name. Therefore: not an rvalue.
    // Therefore: Must move.
    bar(std::move(o));
}

void bar(Object&& o)
{
    // ...
}
```

The rule also works everywhere in your code snippet:

- all the `.size()` return values: no name -> rvalue
- `a`, `b`, `res`, `i` have names -> not rvalues
- the `i!=a.size()` boolean: no name -> rvalue
- the `a[i]+b[i]` temporary: no name -> rvalue

Only the function's return value is more tricky because return value optimization (RVO) plays a role here. The rule of thumb here is: “If you return a local variable there’s usually no need to std::move() it.”

Comment: Are you saying the quote from Stroustrup's book "The res local variable in operator+() for Vectors is an example ", is actuallly wrong?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m saying. But if that’s from a Stroustroup book I assume some kind of mistake or missing context. He definitely knows the language. ;)